# Parsing string as a line of code in C++

Tags: c++, string, plot, cimg

Is it possible that a string variable can be parsed as an actual line of code in C++? For example, can this string, `"x=0"`, be parsed as actual code and set the value of `x` (some random variable in the program) to zero? What I plan to do with this is that I want to make a simple plotter in C++. The user enters the function (The function will be in terms of `x` and `y` and will have the value zero) to plot as a string (like `2*y+x`), which then will be converted to a code object and then evaluated accordingly using a loop.

Comment: Not natively no. You're going to have to make your own system and it's not trivial.

Comment: As far as I know there is no built-in parser in C++ that you could use. But you can try with boost::spirit. Creating a parser for such functions should not be too hard.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a feature that is not natively supported by the language. The quick answer to the question is a simple "No."

Comment: @RSahu So if answer to a question is no, then it is off topic? Thank you for this insight.

Comment: Being impossible doesn't make the question off-topic. Also, this post is under discussion on meta at: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280965/whats-the-best-way-to-respond-to-a-question-which-can-be-answered-simply-by-a/280966#280966

Comment: @crapoverflow, after some consideration, I retracted my vote to close this question as off-topic.

Comment: As it is evident that there isn't any native way to accomplish the aforementioned. Is there any alternate way to get the user to input a function?

Answer (score 1):

Because C++ is a compiled and linked language it is not suitable for on-the-fly evaluation.

But I've achieved something similar to your aims in the past with C++ by [embedding a Python interpretter](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html) to evaluate Python code as strings on the fly and pass the results to the C++ code.

Some other popular scripting languages that can be embedded in a C++ program are [Lua](http://www.lua.org/) and [Squirrel](http://www.squirrel-lang.org/).

In Java I've done the same by embedding a [Groovy interpretter](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Embedding+Groovy).

You need to integrate the scripting language interpretter into your code by "embedding" it and then pass values from the scripting language code to your C++ code by a process of "[marshaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_%28computer_science%29)"

If you really want *C++ syntax* that can be interpretted, it is *theoretically* possible to develop a dynamic parser and interpretter for a *subset* of the language, but C++ is a complex language and such a task would be an *enormous* undertaking fraught with difficulty and essentially a case of using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: See my answer; I think JavaScript has a closer syntax to C/C++ than Java, Python, or any of the other languages mentioned.

Comment: I worked for a project which fired up a C-compiler to «evaluate» C-code. Yikes.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "No".  You can't compile C/C++ "on the fly" like that, as it's a compiled language, not an interpreted one.

But here's an idea: you could embed a JavaScript interpreter, using [the SpiderMonkey API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey), which can interpret all your example code snippets, as JavaScript syntax is very similar to C/C++ in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "Yes". Compiling C++ on the fly works just fine using a C++ JIT. From [llvm.org](http://llvm.org/Features.html)

> A Just-In-Time (JIT) code generation system, which currently supports X86, X86-64, ARM, AArch64, Mips, SystemZ, PowerPC, and PowerPC-64.

The assumption is that you're willing to link most of a compiler into your program in order to achieve this. With concerted effort you should be able to write "eval" on top of the existing API.